# How to setup Google App Service Account OAUTH setup with admin consent?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

We're currently investigating how to send emails on behalf of our users when they authenticate through an OAUTH app.

We can already do this on a per user basis, but we are investigating how to do this for the entire domain for a user.

Is there a way to setup an OAUTH flow where the administrator can authorise once and the service account gets granted permissions for the entire workspace, allowing us to send emails on behalf of all the users of that workspace.

Whatever I read online is that the administrator has to go to admin console and approve all the individual scopes, while I'm already declaring those and they could just accept.

The documentation is confusing so if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Are they users on the domain

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo!

Yes they are. The reason why I'm hinting at domain wide delegation is because our product is tailored towards SME's.

I had hoped I could present them an oauth flow where the administrator approves once and domain wide permissions were given.

The use case for us is to allow sending of email from our platform, but we want to prevent having to onboard every individual from a domain and having them go through the send email permissions oauth flow.

I was hoping domain wide permissions could be granted through the oauth flow by an administrator once.

Comment: Once a service account is configured it should work for everyone on the domain

Comment: Thanks @LindaLawton-DaImTo for clearing the confusion on some of the documentantion. I've got it working now and I'm prompting the admins to configure our service account for the domain.